# Running RoboVM on Android as a pre-compiled app

Tags: android, performance, robovm

My question is an odd one, our company users RoboVM to run our android libGDX game on iOS and it works great.

We have noticed that iOS performance is substantially better, even with all rendering off. We've looked into this very deeply.  It seems that our pure CPU test code is running substantally slower on Android 2.3Ghz device vs 1.3Ghz iOS device running on RoboVM.

By looking into this much deeper we wonder if the pre-compilation that RoboVM is doing is providing a much more performant core loop.  To dig deeper we are very interested in seeing if we can run a RoboVM app on Android. As a pre-compiled optimization for our java code.

We found this example 
https://github.com/staxgr/robovm-ios-android-hybrid

Does anyone know what a process would be for doing this? Or any other pre-compile alternatives for android java code.

Appreciate any help greatly!